# Flexbox works in table in Chrome but not Mozilla

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this table with some content displayed with flexbox working fine in Chrome but not in Mozilla. The thing is that if I put the content out of the table it works but not if is inside. When you resize it looks like the green div has a min-width (Mozilla).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxv0cyLt/) and the code:

```css
.s_container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}
.ssm_opcion {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: inherit;
  background: yellow;
}
.ssm_opcion img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#text_opcion {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: auto;
  -webkit-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto;
  background: green;
}
.test {
  width: 100%;
}
.ti-ar-d {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /*-- horizontal --*/
  align-items: flex-start;
  /*--  vertical  --*/
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  /*-- horizontal --*/
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  /*--  vertical  --*/
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  /*-- horizontal --*/
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  /*--  vertical  --*/
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="s_container">
        <div id="text_opcion" class="ti-me-d">
          <label for="test">
            <p>Prueba</p>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="ssm_opcion">
          <center>
            <img src="images/opciones/mostaza.png">
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Side-by-side Firefox (left) and Chrome here: http://imgur.com/SuLyRmA. Where's the problem?

Comment: When i resize in Mozilla doesn't work like in Chrome. It's like in Mozilla the green div would have a min-width.

Comment: Come on, then please state *in your question* that the problem is visible upon resizing. It saves everyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to flexbox, but to the use of a `<table>`.

You need to add this rule, to avoid your image to break the table layout:

```
.test {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zessx/Lxv0cyLt/2/)

Comment: Something went wrong in your fiddle (the CSS has been replaced by normalize.css boilerplate), but the answer itself does seem to work.  (I totally don't understand why it works though, if you could explain it that'd be very useful)

Comment: @DanielBeck Oops, my bad (link updated). I first tried to add a normalize to check something, and forgot to remove it, but the problem remains the same. Chrome and Firefox doesn't have the same way to calculate how to render table layouts (columns width), and `table-layout:fixed` avoid most of these calculations.